# How do I get the matching values in a csv file?

Tags: c#, csv

So I have a .csv file with 2 columns looking a bit like this:
01,23
02,45
03,178
etc.

Now I want to read the csv file, give it a value for the first column, and get the corresponding value from the second column back. (so say I give it a value of 03, it should give me 178 back)
Here's the code I've got so far but what should go in the if statement?

```
public int CalculateNextLevel(int current_xp, int current_lvl)
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\Lennart\Desktop\Legends of Raymere\Files\Lvl.csv"));
        List<int> levels = new List<int>();
        List<int> exp = new List<int>();
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');

            levels.Add(Convert.ToInt32(values[0]));
            exp.Add(Convert.ToInt32(values[1]));

            foreach (int level in levels)
            {
                if (current_lvl == level)
                {

                }
            }
        }

        return XP_to_nxt_lvl;
    }
```

Comment: Is the first column unique or are duplicates possible?

Comment: Dictionary<int,int> ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter It looks like RPG - level/XP so they are unique

actually in that case just use an array as they are sequential and no holes

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Dictionary` instead

```
var expValues = new Dictionary<int, int>();

while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    var values = line.Split(',');

    expValues.Add(Convert.ToInt32(values[0]), Convert.ToInt32(values[1]));
}

// Retrieve value based on level
if (expValues.ContainsKey(3))
{
   int level03Exp = expValues[3];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string key = "03";
        GetValue(key);        
    }

    private static int GetValue(string key)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");
        var dictonary = lines.ToDictionary(dict =>
        {
            return dict.Split(',')[0];
        });          
        int valInt = int.Parse(dictonary[key].Split(',')[1]);
        return valInt; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Linq like this :

```
 foreach (int level in levels)
            {
                if (current_lvl == level)
                {
                 XP_to_nxt_lvl = exp[levels.IndexOf(level)];
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LINQ` and a [`Lookup<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which allows duplicate keys but is similar to a `Dictionary`. If the key(level) is not present you get an empty collection of xp's:

```
private ILookup<int, int> LevelLookup = null;
public void LoadAllLevels()
{
    LevelLookup = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Temp\Lvl.csv")
        .Select(l => l.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        .Select(cols => 
        {
            int level = 0, xp = 0;
            bool validLine = cols.Length == 2;
            if(validLine)
                validLine = int.TryParse(cols[0].Trim(), out level);
            if(validLine)
                validLine = int.TryParse(cols[1].Trim(), out xp);
            return new{ level, xp, validLine };
        })
        .Where(x => x.validLine)
        .ToLookup(x => x.level, x => x.xp);
}

public int? CalculateNextLevel(int current_xp, int current_lvl)
{
    int? nextLevel = null;
    var xps = LevelLookup[current_lvl];
    if (xps.Any())
        nextLevel = xps.First();
    return nextLevel;
}
```

You only need to initialize it once or when the file changed via `LoadAllLevels()`.

For example:

```
LoadAllLevels();
int level3 = 3;
int level4 = 4;
int? xp3 = CalculateNextLevel(100,level3);
int? xp4 = CalculateNextLevel(150,level4);
```

I have used nullables to differentiate between XP=0 and a level has yet no defined xp.

```
bool hasLev4XP = xp4.HasValue;
if(hasLev4XP)
{
    int lev4XpNeeded = xp4.Value;
}
```

If the level is guaranteed to be unique you could also use `ToDictionary` to create a dictionary and use similar code as above.